# Using Custom AWS Lambda Runtimes with asp.net core

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-lambda

Recently amazon announced support for a custom .net core runtime: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-amazon-lambda-runtimesupport/

My current aws lambda project is written C# using the .NET Core 2.1; 2.2 is not supported yet hence I'd like to use custom runtime.

However, it seems that in order to use the custom runtime, it is necessary to use `LambdaBootstrap`.
From the docs it is not clear to me if it is possible to use it alongside asp.net core: 
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport

p.s. currently my aws lambda is using asp.net core for authentication and other

Comment: are you talking about running a webapp in parallel with the lamda? if so there are surely ways considering asp.net core runs as a console app but don't get why you would want to do it

Comment: thanks; I've edited my question to clarify my situation: my current aws lambda project is written C# using the .NET Core 2.1; 2.2 is not supported yet hence I'd like to use custom runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good demo / tutorial that shows how the author approaches using the lambda bootstrap:

https://medium.com/@dimoss/asp-net-core-2-2-3-0-serverless-web-apis-in-aws-lambda-with-a-custom-runtime-and-lambda-warmer-ce19ce2e2c74

The author uses the following code to switch between local debugging and the lambda entry:

```
public class LocalEntryPoint
{
    private static readonly LambdaEntryPoint LambdaEntryPoint = new LambdaEntryPoint();
    private static readonly Func<APIGatewayProxyRequest, ILambdaContext, Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse>> Func = LambdaEntryPoint.FunctionHandlerAsync;

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
#if DEBUG
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
#else
        // Wrap the FunctionHandler method in a form that LambdaBootstrap can work with.
        using (var handlerWrapper = HandlerWrapper.GetHandlerWrapper(Func, new JsonSerializer()))

        // Instantiate a LambdaBootstrap and run it.
        // It will wait for invocations from AWS Lambda and call the handler function for each one.
        using (var bootstrap = new LambdaBootstrap(handlerWrapper))
        {
            await bootstrap.RunAsync();
        }
#endif
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```